# RecyclerView with custom grid LayoutManager loses views and scrolling synchronization onFling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I have an Activity with 3 RecyclerViews in a ConstraintLayout. One is along the left side of the activity and uses a vertical LinearLayoutManager. One is on the top side of the activity and uses a horizontal LinearLayoutManger. The last one to the right of the first and under the second and using a custom LayoutManager that implements a grid that scrolls both horizontally and vertically. This creates a spreadsheet effect, and I need the RecyclerViews to scroll simultaneously in an direction. This works for the most part, except for the case where there is a quick flinging action. When a fling is detected there are two problems:

1. The RecyclerView using the custom LayoutManager seems to lag and for a time no views are visible in this recycler.

   - I suspect this is because the size of the Views means about 45 are visible each time, so on a fast fling all of these views are being constantly recycled.
2. The scrolling synchronization between RecyclerViews is lost, sometimes they are off by a little but if the list is large then they can be off by quite a bit. This is the more important issue as the views must align correctly to be useful to users. The speed of the fling that causes this is much lower than problem #1

## Current Code

The scroll listener attached to all 3 RecyclerViews:

```
private RecyclerView.OnScrollListener syncScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            if (recyclerAssignment == recyclerView && newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                draggingView = 1;
            } else if (recyclerGrades == recyclerView && newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                draggingView = 2;
            } else if (recyclerStudent == recyclerView && newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                draggingView = 3;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if (draggingView == 1 && recyclerView == recyclerAssignment) {
                recyclerGrades.scrollBy(dx, dy);
            } else if (draggingView == 2 && recyclerView == recyclerGrades) {
                recyclerAssignment.scrollBy(dx, dy);
                recyclerStudent.scrollBy(dx, dy);
            } else if (draggingView == 3 && recyclerView == recyclerStudent) {
                recyclerGrades.scrollBy(dx, dy);
            }
        }
    };
```

The custom LayoutManager is exactly the same as this: https://github.com/devunwired/recyclerview-playground/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/recyclerplayground/layout/FixedGridLayoutManager.java

## What I've Tried

I noticed there is a possibility to add an OnFlingListener but it seems a fling calls the Recycler's scrollBy function, and they have different parameters.

I tried to detect when a scroll state changed to idle in the grid RecyclerView and then scroll the other views, but this caused an infinite loop.

## Further thoughts

I thought it might make sense to extend RecyclerView to override the method that handles a fling, but I'm unsure exactly what to do in that method to make this work correctly.

I understand that to solve problem #1 I probably have to store more views out of frame. This is fine but I'm a big confused on how that logic might work in the LayoutManager.

The layout manager returns a "delta" variable when it scrolls either horizontally or vertically, and the comments mentions this is "for handling flings" but there are no further comments and I don't think this is behaving quite as intended.

Any help solving these two problems is greatly appreciated.

Comment: First Question: Why? If the left and the top recyclers synchronize with the central one, why do you have three instead of one? You are aware that you can have different layouts in a recycler, right? Is this about cell height or width?

Comment: Second Question: Since your code looks okay to me, I feel that you are asking us to debug the layout managers you are using. I would need code running on my machine to do this. Can you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: On a footnote: The only thing about your code which should be changed are the two calls to `super`. Since with the `new` operator and the curly brackets `{}` you are implicitly subclassing `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` and since the (abstract) super class only has empty method bodies for the two methods you are overriding, you need not make any calls there.

Comment: The recyclers have to synchronize because both the top and left recycler need to be sticky, and in addition the top and central recyclers have to implement paging when scrolling horizontally. I'm really not asking for debugging here. My understanding is the recycler should be preparing enough views in advance to handle the scroll, yet this is clearly not happening. My question is really for insight into how I can make this happen.